# how to convert lambda function into a separate function?

Tags: python

I am not sure how to pass argument after converting lambda function into separate function.

Here is the original codes which works.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
aspect=2
tree = BallTree(X,metric="pyfunc",func=lambda p0, p1: math.sqrt((p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[0] - p0[0]) + (p1[1] - p0[1]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) * aspect))
```

since the above lambda function is too long, i'd like define a separate function fromthis lambda function.

```
def elipse(p0,p1,aspect):

   a=math.sqrt((p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[0] - p0[0]) + (p1[1] - p0[1]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) * aspect)  
   return  a

tree = BallTree(X,metric="pyfunc",func=elipse(X.iloc[:,0],X.iloc[:,1],aspect))
```

then i got an error of `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

I am not sure how to pass p0 and p1 , could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: couldn't you simply do `tree = BallTree(X,metric="pyfunc",func=elipse(p0,p1,aspect))` ?

Comment: @BetinhoSaad The `func` argument has to be a function reference, not a call to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `elipse()` takes 3 arguments, but `BallTree()` only supplies 2 arguments, you can still use a `lambda`, but it's simpler because the long equation is in the function.

```
tree = BallTree(X,metric="pyfunc",func=lambda p0, p1: elipse(p0, p1, aspect))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you now have a named function, you just need to tell `BallTree` what that name is:

```py
tree = BallTree(X,metric="pyfunc",func=elipse)
```

Also, you don't need to have `aspect` as a parameter:

```py
def elipse(p0, p1):
    aspect = 2
    return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[0] - p0[0]) + (p1[1] - p0[1]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) * aspect)
```

Comment: `elipse` takes 3 arguments, `BallTree()` only calls it with 2 arguments.

Comment: yes with 3 arguments, how to do it? If I remove 3rd argument of aspect, it works fine with just func=elipse, but with 3 arguments, the error said elipse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'aspect'

Comment: I assumed that `aspect` is something that can vary, so you can't hard-code it into the function.

Comment: @Barmar: I see what you are saying, but I'm currently assuming its part of some formula that was used. I've just put that parameter as a constant inside the function for now.